# Custom client/server protocol in Scala

Tags: scala, client-server, protocols, messaging

Suppose I need to implement a custom message-oriented protocol in Scala. I need to implement also the client/server code.

I would define "cases classes" for protocol messages as follows:

```
trait Message
case class Request1(...) extends Message
case class Response1(...) extends Message
case class Request2(...) extends Message
case class Response2(...) extends Message
... // other requests/responses
```

Now I need functions to read/write the messages from/to input/output streams and handle the messages.

```
def read(in: InputStream): Message = {...}

def write(msg: Message, out: OutputStream) {...}

def handle(msg:Message): Message = msg match {
  case req: Request1 = ... // handle Request1
  case resp: Response1 = ... // handle Response1
  ... // cases for all other message types
}
```

I guess it works but I wonder if I can improve the solution. How would you correct or improve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [Akka](http://akka.io)?

Akk makes it much simpler to develop distributed applications, **no need to define input and output streams manually**. Just have a look at the "Remoting" example on the [homepage](http://akka.io).

The benefits of this approach would be that you can **focus on the protocol itself**, i.e., in your case the development of one (or more) actors on the client side, and one (or more) actors on the server side.

Akka should provide you with all 'lower-level' functionality you need, taking care of the actual sending an receiving of the messages, multi-threading, and so on; so you don't have to re-invent the wheel. This should also make your code easier to maintain by others in the future, as Akka is a well-known toolkit.

To get a basic idea of how actors work, have a look at [this book chapter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/actors-and-concurrency.html), but note that it describes the Scala actors, which have been replaced by Akka actors in the meantime. If you want to dig deeper, I'd recommend [*Akka Concurrency*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531660), which is more up to date.

Comment: How is it changes the way **protocol** works and handled? Inside actor you will have the very same handle method (apart from akka-fsm)

Comment: Sure, it does *not* affect the way the protocol works, but it avoids re-inventing the wheel (from the question: _Now I need functions to read/write the messages from/to input/output streams and handle the messages._), hence saves development time, and also makes it easier for others to read and maintain the code, as Akka is a well-known library (e.g. one would not have to look up how exactly 'handle' works, because how 'receive' works is already known, and so on). I tried to clarify this in my answer, thanks.